# Reportings Services (SSRS) - Avoid asking user/password when accessing reports

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have granted a group to access the reports deployed. When a user that is member of that group access to:

http://serverIP/ReportServer

in order to see a report, then a popup authentication window appears asking for user/password. I would like to avoid this, I mean, I would like that all the members of that group can access to reports page without being asked for a user/password. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it so that the credentials required to access the database are embedded in the datasource you use.

In report builder try right clicking your datasource accessing the properties and changing the credentials. You can change "prompt for credentials" to "use this username and password" and then enter a username and password with the correct level of access to the underlying database.

If you are using a shared datasource ie not one embedded in your report but a general one then you will need to change the settings of that instead.